# query to retrieve last record from multiple rows with common column data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve last entered data from a table which has multiple rows of common column data.There a id called Tno and column2 as Email which is common for three rows, I want to retrieve the last entered row

```
   Tno  Email              pdesc             Activity
   A20  nancy@example.com      not working           Step1
   A20  nancy@example.com      Change the version    Step2
   A20  nancy@example.com      Still not working     step3          



SELECT * FROM `supactive2` WHERE Tno='A20' ORDER BY `Tno` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

As of now im using this query, but I get only the first record( `A20 -nancy@example.com-not working- Step1`)
I need the last record`(ie. A20 - nancy@example.com -  still not working -  step3)`.

Comment: Try to add primary key column to your table and use it for ordering.

Comment: Or at-least there must be a column which differentiates the last entered record, like datetime.

Comment: What is the table sorted by? What are the table keys?

Answer (score 0):

Add a datetime constraint to the table so that u can sort by timestamp.
Or if your activity field gets populated in the sequential order then sort by activity e.g. step1 , step2 , step3

Answer (score 0):

Order by Activity, will get you the result.

SELECT * FROM `supactive2` WHERE Tno='A20' ORDER BY `Tno`, Activity DESC LIMIT 1;